# How to install packages on debian lenny 5.0

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, aptitude, packages, optical-media

I'm working with Debian Lenny 5.0 and I'm trying to replicate an environment. The problem is that when I try to update aptitude.. it looks like the servers aren't online anymore.

Is there any way for me to install some libraries by aptitude (libraries/apps I need for example: libreadline5-dev, make, SNMP, etc) with online servers? If so, which ones?

I've already searched on the Internet and I've been thinking about using a full package dvd and try to install all I need. Is there any possibility to go on with this approach?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Lenny isn't actively supported anymore, the archives are still available, you need to edit /etc/apt/sources.list - the link is in german, but you'll get the picture: http://www.redirect301.de/debian-lenny-sources-list-2012.html

Comment: The packages have been moved to `archive` as Lenny is no longer supported. Debian [still has them](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/) but you should probably find an archive mirror to use instead.

Comment: You should really update to a distribution that is supported. Lenny hasn't been supported for awhile now, and so it hasn't been receiving security updates.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb     http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny main non-free contrib
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian lenny main non-free contrib
```

Then do everything you can to get this system upgraded as soon as possible.  :)